# creating draggable on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can a draggable in jquery UI be created on the fly with response to an event? Since event can be multiple, how can each freshly created draggable be assigned a different ID for the forthcoming use?

Comment: lol!Completely forgot the grammer...Thanks...edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an element draggable with `$("#your-id").draggable();`

Do you want to create a new element during an event like this?

```
function yourEventHandler()
{
 $("BODY").append(
  $('<DIV id="#my-div" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red"></div>')
 );
 $("#my-div").draggable();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I intend to do. However, since I am newbie, I tried your code exactly as above but doesn't work. Is it just a pseudo-code or real one?

Comment: I didn't test it at all so call it pseudo-code. Did you get an error or it doesn't seem to do anything? You should post what you've tried or what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. It works fine now. # should not be on DIV id when using append. By the way, how can I pass <div> ID as a variable or function eventhandler argument?

Comment: $("#my-div").attr("id") ? Which event do you mean?

Comment: For example, in above, function yourEventHandler(ID_Name)...How can the newly created <DIV> be made to take ID_Name as its id? for $("#my-div").attr("id"), I want <div> to take ID_Name as id? How can it be used before assigning ID? Sorry if it does not make good sense due to my poor description.

Comment: You should post what code you have so far in http://jsfiddle.net it's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
var currItems = 0;

$('<div>').attr('id', currItems++).appendTo('body').draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use the .delegate() method to listen for the source of the event (e.g. a click?) and then you can use the "target" argument to bind jQuery UI .draggable() to the target - probably like this:

`$(event.target).draggable(objDragSettings);`

where `objDragSettings` defines any presets.